# how to get current record id using onchange for one2many in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have tried below code for onchange function but return some unreadable code

```py
class sales_targets(models.Model):
    _name = 'sale.target'

    category = fields.Selection([
        ('normal', 'Product'), ('cloud', 'Cloud EYE'), ('tech', 'Technical Support Group'), ('db', 'Database'),
        ('odoo', 'Odoo'), ('can', 'CAN'), ('tod', 'TOD'), ('rental', 'Rental'), ('tec', 'TEC'), ('top', 'TOP'),
        ('tor', 'TOR'), ('tos', 'TOS'),
        ('aws', 'AWS')], 'Category', default='normal',
        help="A category of the view type is a virtual category that can be used as the parent of another category to create a hierarchical structure.")
    team_ids=fields.Many2many('crm.team','team_target_rel','target_ids','team_id','Sales Team')
    from_date=fields.Date('Budget From Date')
    to_date = fields.Date('Budget To Date')
    no_call=fields.Float('No of Calls')
    target_line=fields.One2many('target.line','target_id','Target Line', copy=True)




    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('team_ids')
    def _onchange_tem_salesperson(self):
        print ".....",self.id,self._origin
```

above code onchange function result is

```
...... <odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7f72aff2b290> sale.target()
```

Comment: Try: `self.env.context.get('active_id')`

Comment: it return **None**

Comment: Remove `@api.multi`, try again

Comment: again returns **None**

Comment: now what is the output of `self.id`.

Comment: <odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7f0de7a6f650>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154002/discussion-between-kln-and-kbir).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for you advice and then finally got solution for this page [How to pass value with onchange one2many variable in odoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842073/how-to-pass-value-with-onchange-one2many-variable-in-odoo) please up vote my question if my question is worth

Answer (score 3):

In onchange event odoo create a dummy record for you.
In order to get the id, odoo passes the record in origin property.

```
   self._origin.id. # keep in mind in create id is instance of NewId object Not integer
```

I'm not sure if it's self. _origin or  self.origin but i'm sure that it's in origin because i used it before. Hope it helped you

Comment: it returns False

Comment: Try self.env._origin.  I'm on my phone if you are good in debug mode search where you can find this origin property just put a breakpoint and check the content of self

Comment: What still nothing my friend

Comment: ok.. how can i pass based on many2many field on-change, need to pass domain to one2many

Comment: thanks for you advice and then finally got solution for this page [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842073/how-to-pass-value-with-onchange-one2many-variable-in-odoo]   please up vote my question if my question is worth